# Get content length of response without waiting for the entire response?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-http

I have an app built on Ionic 3.x.x that has some API calls where I make HTTP requests; these requests have responses with an amount of data that varies greatly depending on what kind of data the user requests; since there's a lot of data on the response, it takes a while to download it and I'd like to read the response headers so I can show the user how much data is actually being downloaded.

The issue at hand is that, currently, the response headers can only be accessed after the entire response has been received, so it doesn't help.

The function that makes the API call is a simple request, implemented as part of a service:

```
getData(...){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    ...

    return this.http.get(url, { headers: headers }).map(data => {    
        return data;
    }).catch(error => {
        return Observable.throw(error.status);
    });
}
```

Which is called by another function, defined elsewhere:

```
this.web.getData(...).subscribe( data => {
    ...do stuff with data here
});
```

If I use `.subscribe()` instead of `.map()` in the `getData()` function, I'll have access to the response headers as soon as possible, but it'll return a subscription which can't be subscribed to, so I can't use it the function's return where I currently do.

Comment: service should return the `length` as the first property

Comment: Could you expand that explanation?